# ajax dropdown showing replacing dashes with a weird character

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When my ajax dropdown pulls data from database it is replacing the dashes with this character ¬, how do I stop it from showing this character?

[image]

Comment: Hi there. In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what the issue was. The preferred collation in the database should be set to **utf8_general_ci**, in order to remove that character and get the dashes to show up.